# Cakephp url parameter encoding problem?

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp, I would like to use an url parameter which might contain some special chars like é or è.

When I print $this->params['url'] for this url for example:
http://dev.family/registration?fname=kr%E9s

I get:
`Array ( [url] => registration [fname] => kr�s )`

So the é becomes a question mark.

I tried urldecode, but I doesn't help. I guess this has something to do with UTF-8 encoding, but I don't know where to search.

Any suggestions?

Krikke

Comment: What character encoding are you using?

Comment: It should be UTF-8, but I guess it is not.. How can I make sure it's UTF-8? Do I need to change something in my config?

Answer (score 1):

Try `htmlentities()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the problem thanks to B7ackAnge7z.

The `htmlentities` function worked, but translates `krés` to `kr&eacute;s`. This fixes the problem with the question mark.

But.. I want to use this value to pre-fill a form input. So the input would contain `kr&eacute;s`, which is not what I intented.

So I prefill it with this value now:

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities($this->params['url']['fname']), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```

-> convert the value with htmlentities and then decode it again to UTF-8.
Somewhat a dirty fix...

I guess cake doesn't decode URL parameters to UTF-8 default or maybe I should worry about an encoding problem somewhere in my cake project?

Thx!